# Why do we need the negative sign in TR2 (the "turning triangle" axiom) in the definition of triangulated categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, triangulated-categories

In the TR2 of the [definition of triangulated categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_category), we add a negative sign to an arrow when we turn the triangles. What is the significance/motivation of that negative sign ($-u[1]$ as in the Wikipedia)? It would be great if there is an example illustrating this (like the trouble we will have when we change the definition by removing the negative sign).

My question is different from this one [What does this sign mean in the definition of triangulated categories?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1908342)